# Replace eval with something else

Tags: java, linux, bash, eval

I'm trying to replace an `eval` in my code with something else. What I currently have that is working:

```
#$1 command "command"
#$2 params "--source='Waiting b'"
fun_example(){
  eval java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" \  
  -Duser.language="en" -Dspring.profiles.active="x" -jar /x.jar \
  ${1} $(echo ${2} | sed "s|'|\"|g")
}
```

I tried various things but nothing worked. The main issue is that in any other way the application receives params with quotes example "Waiting" and if I don't put any " then the params get cut off if it has any spaces Waiting instead of Waiting b. I could probably change it inside the application to remove quotes but I want to avoid this.

If I do it like this then I get the mentioned problem.

```
java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" \  
-Duser.language="en" -Dspring.profiles.active="x" -jar /x.jar \
${1} $(echo ${2} | sed "s|'|\"|g")
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: The main problem is that my command is stored in an env variable!

Comment: You need to decide what the semantics should be. If you chose `system(3)` style semantics of the application passing shell quoted words and you're unwilling to change it, then you can't and shouldn't get rid of `eval` because you've essentially defined your interface in terms of it. A better choice is `execve(2)` semantics where the application passes multiple arguments, in which case you can just trivially, safely and robustly use `"$@"`

Answer (score 0):

SO after a lot of pain and some helpful advice from @thatootherguy I've ended up using this solution

```
fun_example_call() {
    export LANG=C.UTF-8
    COMMAND=(java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar /x.jar "$@")
    "${COMMAND[@]}"
    status=$?

    if [[ ${status} -eq 0 ]]
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}


#$1 = command "example_command"
#$2 = params - example params "test='wow' wow='test'"
fun_example(){
    IFS="'" read -r -a array <<< $2
    RUN_ARRAY=("fun_example_call" $1)
    for (( VAR = 0; VAR < ${#array[@]}; VAR+=2 )); do
        RUN_ARRAY+=(${array[$VAR]}"${array[$VAR+1]}")
    done
    "${RUN_ARRAY[@]}"
}
```

Hopefully, this helps out someone. Like @thatootherguy said the goal is to have an array of params so that we don't trigger the system(3) style semantics